# How to disable ctrl+wheel font resize in konsole/yakuake

Tags: mouse, konsole

Which is quite annoying when I mistouch touchpad with two fingers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to *Settings->Edit Current Profile*.  Select the *Mouse* tab.  There's a check box there:

```
Allow Ctrl+scrollwheel to zoom text size.
```

Untick that and click `Apply`.

Comment: Probably useless information but who knows? The patch including this feature has been pushed on Nov. 2012. https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/107281/